# Merging multiple dataframes (time series)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge a list of dataframe.
It's a time series, each dataframe has the same columns.
They contain the same id points, the only variables that change are the `utc` and `temp`.

df1

```
id          name2       geom            utc                             temp                                                                        
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   15.3
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   17.3
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2020-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   10.0
```

df2

```
id          name2       geom            utc                             temp                                                                        
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   11.3
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   10.3
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   12.0
```

df3

```
id          name2       geom            utc                             temp                                                                        
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   13.3
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   18.3
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   12.0
```

(...)

My output should be something like this:

```
id          name2       geom            utc                             temp                                                                        
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   15.3
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   11.3
140826      AAA140826   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   13.0
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   17.3
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   10.3
140827      AAA140827   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   18.0
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-07-01T00:00:00.000000000   10.0
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-08-01T00:00:00.000000000   12.0
140828      AAA140828   POLYGON ((...)) 2010-09-01T00:00:00.000000000   12.0
```

I did something similar previously but each dataframe had a different variable.
I tried to use pd.merge and merge one by one but i get the error `Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'temp_x'} is not allowed`.

Thank you everybody for your help !

Comment: `out = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` optionally `out = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values(by='id', ignore_index=True)`

Comment: use following code: `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_values('id').reset_index()`